# Single word for 25%

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the word to use if I want to name a variable that holds 25% of something, like for example:

**Interest Income** = `InterestIncome`

**50% Interest Income** = `HalfInterestIncome` or `HalfOfInterestIncome`

**25% Interest Income** = `_____InterestIncome`

I tried searching for ["single word for 25%"](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=single+word+for+25%25&oq=single+word+for+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i57j0l3.4316j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but didn't show any promising results.

Comment: A *quarter*, perhaps?

Comment: Requests to help name something are out of scope and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”; “[Help naming something – Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=help+naming+something)”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quarter interest because quarter represents one fourth of anything.one fourth of 100% is 25%.